# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for

Tags: java, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am new to the world of maven. I am trying to create a dummy spring boot project using **Spring Tool Suite** in a *private company*. Whenever I try to create a spring-boot project, I get the following error. Does it have something to do with a *private network*?? If not, is there any problem with my maven installation? How do I make this run?

Here's the error:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.example.dummy:dummy-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
>   from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced.
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
>   from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot):
>   repo.spring.io and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local
>   POM   pom.xml /dummy-project  line 14 Maven pom Loading Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pom.xml` file of your project has a so-called parent pom. That parent-pom is just another pom file which sits on the spring.io server. Maven downloads that pom file and merges its configuration with the configuration of your project's pom.

Therefore, maven needs to have access to https://repo.spring.io/snapshot to download the parent-pom. Since the parent-pom will be cached in your local maven repository, you will only require access to that server once.